# Customizing Django admin with list_display?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to customize the Django Admin.

```
models.py 
=============
class Question(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

admin.py
===========   
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'poll'. 'pub_date')
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Question)
```

That seems to be the correct setup for customizing the QuestionIndex.
I want this displayed:
    What is your question?     introPoll   July 31, 2009

However, the only the default **unicode** is showing up on the Question index.

Am I missing a step?

What could be some reasons the additional data is not being displayed on the index?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must specify the admin class in the `admin.site.register` function if you've customized it:

`admin.site.register(Question, QuestionAdmin)`

Also, I assume it's a typo, but the `list_display` has a period where there should be a comma: `('name', 'poll'. 'pub_date')` should be `('name', 'poll', 'pub_date')`.